# Problems saving a xml file in Android

Tags: android, xml, save, internal-storage

I am trying to save an array list into a xml file in the internal storage using Xmlserializer. The app scans for BLE and when a Stop button is pressed it should save some parameters from the list of BLE that it has detected. It runs perfect and when I pressed the stop button it stops the scan and displays in the mobile screen a toast message that the xml file has been created successfully. However, when I seach for the xml file, it doesn´t appear anywhere as if it hasn´t been created. I don´t know the reason of this problem. Here is the code I have implemented:

```
package com.example.newblescan;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer;

import com.example.newblescan.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Xml;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.newblescan.adapter.BleDevicesAdapter;

/**
* Activity for scanning and displaying available Bluetooth LE devices.
*/
public class DeviceScanActivity extends ListActivity {

private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 100;

private BleDevicesAdapter leDeviceListAdapter;
private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
private Scanner scanner;
private Save save;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_devices);

    // Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device.  Then you can
    // selectively disable BLE-related features.
    if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }

    // Initializes a Bluetooth adapter.  For API level 18 and above, get a reference to
    // BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
            (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    // Checks if Bluetooth is supported on the device.
    if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gatt_scan, menu);
    if (scanner == null || !scanner.isScanning()) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(null);
    } else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(
                R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_scan:
            leDeviceListAdapter.clear();
            if (scanner == null) {
                scanner = new Scanner(bluetoothAdapter, mLeScanCallback);
                scanner.startScanning();

                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.menu_stop:
            if (scanner != null) {
                save = new Save(leDeviceListAdapter);
                scanner.stopScanning();
                try {
                    save.savedata();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                scanner = null;


                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Ensures Bluetooth is enabled on the device.  If Bluetooth is not currently enabled,
    // fire an intent to display a dialog asking the user to grant permission to enable it.
    if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        final Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        return;
    }

    init();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // User chose not to enable Bluetooth.
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            finish();
        } else {
            init();
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (scanner != null) {
        scanner.stopScanning();
        scanner = null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    final BluetoothDevice device = leDeviceListAdapter.getDevice(position);
    if (device == null)
        return;

    //final Intent intent = new Intent(this, DeviceServicesActivity.class);
    //intent.putExtra(DeviceServicesActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
    //intent.putExtra(DeviceServicesActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS, device.getAddress());
    //startActivity(intent);
}



private void init() {
    if (leDeviceListAdapter == null) {
        leDeviceListAdapter = new BleDevicesAdapter(getBaseContext());
        setListAdapter(leDeviceListAdapter);
    }

    if (scanner == null) {
        scanner = new Scanner(bluetoothAdapter, mLeScanCallback);
        scanner.startScanning();
    }

    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

// Device scan callback.
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        leDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device, rssi);
                        leDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }
        };



private static class Scanner extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private final BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback;

    private volatile boolean isScanning = false;

    Scanner(BluetoothAdapter adapter, BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback callback) {
        bluetoothAdapter = adapter;
        mLeScanCallback = callback;
    }

    public boolean isScanning() {
        return isScanning;
    }

    public void startScanning() {
        synchronized (this) {
            isScanning = true;
            start();
        }
    }

    public void stopScanning() {
        synchronized (this) {
            isScanning = false;
            bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    if (!isScanning)
                        break;

                    bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                }

                sleep(SCAN_PERIOD);

                synchronized (this) {
                    bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
        } finally {
            bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
    }
}


public class Save {   

  /**
 * 
 */

private BleDevicesAdapter leDeviceListAdapter;

Save(BleDevicesAdapter BLEList) {

    leDeviceListAdapter = BLEList;

}

public void savedata() throws FileNotFoundException{

    String filename = "Dragon.txt";
    //String date = (DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", new java.util.Date()).toString());


    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    int size = leDeviceListAdapter.getCount(); 
    //Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    //long timestamp = extras.getLong("currentTime");
    try {
    fos= openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
    serializer.setOutput(fos, "UTF-8");
    serializer.startDocument(null, Boolean.valueOf(true));
    serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);

    serializer.startTag("", "root");
    //serializer.startTag("", "timestamp");
    //serializer.text(date);
    //serializer.endTag("", "timestamp");

    for(int j = 0 ; j < size ; j++)
    {
        BluetoothDevice devices = leDeviceListAdapter.getDevice(j);
        //Integer signal = leDeviceListAdapter.getRSSI(j);
        serializer.startTag("", "name");
        serializer.text(devices.getName());
        serializer.endTag("", "name");

        serializer.startTag("", "address");
        serializer.text(devices.getAddress());
        serializer.endTag("", "address");

        //serializer.startTag(null, "rssi");
        //serializer.setProperty(null, signal);
        //serializer.endTag(null, "rssi");
    }
    //ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    //out.write((int) timestamp);
    //out.writeObject(leDeviceListAdapter);
    //out.close();
    serializer.endDocument();
    serializer.flush();
    fos.close();
    Toast.makeText(DeviceScanActivity.this, R.string.list_saved, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
 }

}
```

In the class Save, I implement the method savedata to save the list into a xml file.

Does anyone know what is the problem? Pleasee help!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

openFileOutput puts it in the /data/data/your_packagename/files directory. This directory can only be read by root and by your app-  you will not be able to find the file in any other program without rooting your device.  You will not be able to find it in a file explorer unless you have root access.  If you want to be able to see the file, you need to write it somewhere world accessible, such as the sd card.

Comment: and how I do it to be the file world accessible or, as you has told, in the sd card??

Comment: don't use openFileOutput.  Use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to get the sd card directory, and write to a file in there.